# Can I use git-svn and look like I was using SVN, if yes how?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'm used to git and I like it very much, but one of my client is (still?) using subversion, I don't really now about svn, but I know there a git-svn package.

I know it's possible to fetch a repo from svn with git, but can i use git instead of svn and still commit, and "push" to the central svn server?

I want to use git and not svn if I can can you point me any tutorial to do so?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I actually don't care to fetch ALL the commits, only the 10/20 previous one would be enough as the application is in a working state and that's only about doing improvements so I will only fetch all the commit history if it's actually needed.

Comment: "and look like I was using SVN" -- If it's truly important that none of the other svn users know you've been using git, then be careful not to commit your `.gitignore` file or anything like that, and never `git svn dcommit` more than one commit at a time because they will be just a few seconds apart in the svn logs. But other than that, you can think of git as just a very fancy svn client and no one will know the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git-svn` provides a bridge from Git and SVN. It will behave like vanilla Git locally, but as soon as you try to push or pull your changes to or from master, it gets completely different.

Instead of doing a push, you will use `git commit` to commit locally, and `git svn dcommit` to push your local commits to SVN.

The git-svn [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) explains how to pull from a SVN repository. Note that it is *extremely* slow (compared to normal git) because it fetches every revision from SVN. See the examples at the bottom of the documentation.

Here it a typical way I've used it:

1. `git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project -T trunk -b branches -t tags` - The URL is your SVN repo, and you specify the -T, -b, and -t switches to specify sub paths in your SVN directory. Git will then use these SVN directories to look for branches and tags, and trunk as master.
2. Make some code changes
3. `git add...` to stage your changes
4. `git commit...` to commit your changes locally.
5. `git svn dcommit` to push the local commits to SVN. For each local commit, Git will make these separate commits on the SVN server.

Comment: I tried your git svn clone command, but that does nothing, I previously checked out the svn repo (with svn) it seems there isn't any, trunk, tags, or branches folder, all the code is at the root, any ideas?

Comment: It's ok I achieved to clone by not specifying any parameters

Comment: @EricP: That was the way to handle it, yes.

Comment: Just a last, thing, I know now how to "push" (using svn dcommit) but how to "pull" ? Is git-svn fetch enough?

Comment: @EricP: You are probably looking for `git svn rebase` According to the docs... " This fetches revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD and rebases the current (uncommitted to SVN) work against it. This works similarly to svn update..."

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but i think the best is that one changes version control app :)

to get the svn commits to git (after you have already git svn initialized it of course)

`git svn fetch`

To get your git commits to svn

`git commit`
`git svn dcommit`

Comment: I don't think my client will accept to migrate from svn to git :) But I wish :D